# How to prevent saving of Outlook.AppointmentItem in case some rules are broken defined by Outlook Plugin

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I want to write an OutlookPlugin which prevents the user from saving / updating an AppointmentItem in case the title is shorter than n characters. 
I can handly the updateEvent (Item_Change) event. But it does not prevent Outlook from finally saving the title anyways.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try hooking into the AppointmentItem.Write event.  You can set the Cancel argument to false to prevent the changes from being saved.